# Proof that if $Z = X + Y$, where $X\text{~Bin}(n, p)$ and $Y\text{~Bin}(m, p)$ and are independent, then $Z\text{~Bin}(n + m, p)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I had to prove this theorem.

> If $X\text{~Bin}(n, p)$ and $Y\text{~Bin}(m, p)$ are independent random variables then $$Z=(X+Y)\text{~Bin}(n + m, p)$$

My proof: If we consider $Z = X + Y$, then $E(Z) = E(X + Y) \implies E(Z) = E(X) + E(Y)$ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent. We know that for a binomial distribution, the mean is the product of the two parameters. $$\therefore E(X) = n\cdot p$$$$\text{and, } E(Y) = m\cdot p$$
Then we will have, $$E(Z) = n\cdot p + m\cdot p$$ $$\implies E(Z) = (n + m)\cdot p$$
This corresponds to a binomial distribution where the number of trials is $(n + m)$ and the probability of success is $p$. From this, we can conclude $Z\text{~Bin}(n + m, p)$.

Is this proof correct? Are there alternate ways to prove this?

Comment: How do you know that $Z$ has a binomial distribution at all to begin with?

Comment: And how do you know, for example, that $Z$ isn't $\operatorname{Bin}(2n+2m, p/2)$ or other choice of parameters giving the same first moment?

Comment: Hint: Binomial(n, p) is just the sum of n Bernoulli(p).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also apply the Law of Total Probability and the independence of $X$ and $Y$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Z = z) & = \mathbb{P}(X + Y = z)\\
& = \sum_{x = 0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X = x, Y = z - x)\\
& = \sum_{x = 0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X = x)\mathbb{P}(Y = z - x)\\
& = \sum_{x = 0}^{z}{n\choose x}p^{x}(1 - p)^{n - x}{m\choose z - x}p^{z - x}(1 - p)^{m - z + x}\\
& = \sum_{x = 0}^{z}{n\choose x}{m\choose z - x}p^{z}(1 - p)^{m + n - z}\\
& = {n + m\choose z}p^{z}(1 - p)^{m + n - z}
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This is not sufficient; it only shows that the means match.  But distributions are much more than their means.

What you need to argue is simple: making $x$ binomial($p$) decisions "followed by" $y$ binomial($p$) decisions is the same as making $(x+y)$ binomial($p$) decisions.

Comment: May I ask what you mean when you say "followed by"?

Comment: You may!   If there's no connection "followed by" is the same as "independent", but slightly more concrete.